# border-radius issue with input type text

Tags: html, css

I have this issue with `<input type="text">`where I see some extra border in top and left of the input box.

I have this CSS code -

```
#add{
      width: 60%;
      height: 25px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: auto;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

I am attaching the screenshot from chrome. Firefox shows the same thing.[image: Google Chrome Screen Shot]

Comment: Try setting the border to `border: none`

Comment: Please provide more relevant HTML/CSS, or better, reproduce your problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: try `white-space` in your div.

Comment: simply add `border-radius: 10px !important;`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try

```
    #add{
      width: 60%;
      height: 25px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: none; /* <-- This thing here */
      border:solid 1px #ccc;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

By setting it to `border:none` the default css of the text field will be gone and your ready to style it for yourself.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HrtQz/8/)

Comment: Thanks Deadpool. So I should do that when I have border-radius or I need to style my border most of the times as a best practice.

Comment: More or less yes so that the browser default css won't cause any trouble. + your text-field will look the same in different browsers.

Answer (score 4):

```
#add {
    width: 60%;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Border auto is doing that for you. So have your own defined border style.

Comment: Thanks Amit. That's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in Chrome that the user agent style that causes this specific look is `border-style: inset;` You can see it in the snippet below. Chrome is handy about indicating the user agent styles. I found two ways to fix this appearance.

1. Simply set `border: 1px solid black;` and you notice that the border will lose that inset look.
2. If you want extra caution, you can set `border-style: none;` This will cause the border to disappear altogether. You can then set the border as you wish.

I would test any of these solutions across different browsers.

**Chrome User Agent Stylesheet:**

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    cursor: text;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: inset; /* This rule adds the inset border */
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting the `border: none;` will override/nullify the default input css of the text field and then you can add your own custom css to beautify the input text element like so:

```
border: none; /*removes the default css*/
border: 1px solid black; /*your custom css*/
border-radius: 10px; /*your-border radius*/
```

However the above method is ***unnecessarily tedious*** whereas you could achieve the same result in just a single line with:

```
border-radius: 10px !important; /*this simply does the trick!!!*/

**Note:** The !important property in CSS is used to provide more weight (importance) 
than normal property. It means that “this is important”, ignore all the subsequent 
rules
```

Answer (score -4):

`<input type="text" style="border-radius: 25px;" />` 100% works
Try this thing