# border-radius giving weird outline

Tags: css

I've tried this in my project, on jsfiddle etc.

why am I getting a weird grey outline here: [image]

all I have applied is:

```css
    .myInput{
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 20px;
    
    }
```

```html
<input class="myInput" />
```

I obviously just want it to be like this without the dary grey outline...

Comment: Why not post the fiddle on here so we can actually see what's happening

Comment: Use `border-style: solid;` to override the default for what looks like an `<input>`, or remove the border completely with `border-width: 0;`.

Comment: @TheWalrus https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it could of taken you less than 2 seconds to post your fiddle which you already made. I didn't downvote but I imagine people downvote because the question shows a lack of research

Comment: @Huangism yeh fair enough, but I did post code so doesn't show a lack of research, but yes noted for future posts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [border-radius issue with input type text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049674/border-radius-issue-with-input-type-text)

Comment: *takes 2 seconds to replicate*, we are offering our time for free here, so saving our time is the least you can do to show that you consider our time to be valuable. But more importantly, your question failed to mention critical elements, how could we know that you were applying the CSS to an `input` element? Some of us guessed it, but if their guess was wrong, they would've wasted their time trying to answer an incomplete question.

Comment: @RacilHilan agreed but there are a lot of people on this site who love a downvote at any opportunity...

and I did show some code including an input element so not sure how you drew that conclusion. but alas, I have my answer so thanks :)

Comment: *I did show some code including an input element*, no you did not. And that's exactly why I downvoted your question. Rick edited your question and added the missing `input` element, then I removed my downvote. But sadly not everybody comes back and change their vote, so if you mentioned the `input` element from the beginning or provided a fiddle, you most likely would've avoided the downvotes. Your question was even one step from getting closed. Remember that for your next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it with "border:none" or something similar. Take a look at the [border property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) for more info.

I've used "1px solid black" in the example below.

```css
.myInput{
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input class="myInput" />
```

### Extra notes

The reason you're seeing this behaviour is because the browser will apply a default style to your elements. By not overwriting them with CSS your elements will adhere to said style. You don't really notice this when you don't add a border-radius because Chrome (I tested on Chrome) outlines input fields with a teeny tiny grey border. Once you add the border-radius however things become more noticeable.

The answer, therefore, is to take a look at the available border properties to style the input how you'd like, rather than relying on the default styling of the browser.

Comment: Hi pete, I clearly state that you can use border:none to get rid of the border as well but that doesn't show up in the code snippet. (it won't be outlined)

The problem is that every browser gives all of the elements a certain default style to make things look semi-ok. The style the OP is talking about is the default style of an input field on Chrome based browsers.

I will ammend my answer to reflect this, thanks.

Comment: @TheWalrus no problem, we've all pulled our hair out because of some nasty css issue before. Glad to be of help!