# border radius creating a black color

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am creating a SignUp page in which there are 3 input fields.
After applying the border-radius, **black borders** are created around the inputs when I **didn't applied border color to black**.
Is **border-collapse property / border-color** is the issue?

After applying **border-style:none**
[image]

so the initial look is like this:-
[image]

After applying border-radius,
[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

form {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.field {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 38px;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.email {
  border-radius: initial;
}

.top {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.password {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="title">Daily Newsletters Mail Service</h2>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <h2>Sign-In</h2>
    <input class="field top" type="text" name="username" autofocus="true">
    <input class="field email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="xyz@email.com">
    <input class="field password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Yx73@ysd">
    <input class="field bottom" type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign-Up">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR. Set your intended border color to override default

Browsers have a certain default style values per HTML elements (e.g. color, width, margin, etc). Because you define a part of `border` style set (e.g. `border-radius`) but not *all* , the browser simply uses its default values. In this case, the border color of black.

You can just assign your preferred border color and style. See the code snippet below, where I added a `border` style to `input` element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

form {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.field {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 38px;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

input {
  /* Set your intended border color here */ 
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.email {
  border-radius: initial;
}

.top {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.password {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.bottom {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title">Daily Newsletters Mail Service</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
  <h2>Sign-In</h2>
  <input class="field top" type="text" name="username" autofocus="true">
  <input class="field email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="xyz@email.com">
  <input class="field password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Yx73@ysd">
  <input class="field bottom" type="submit" name="signup" value="Sign-Up">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding styling for inputs:

`input { border:none; }` will get rid of them altogether

or `input { border:1px red solid }` will give a red border to each.

Answer (score 0):

###### [Refer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51452829/14862885)

As said in reference,chrome in default sets, `border-style:inset;`.
This doesn't trigger on the first photo (without border-radius) as you have not included any border-related styles to input, like you didn't use *border/border-radius/border-color/border-width/border-style*,
But on second photo as you used border-radius,
other styles like border-colour,and **`border-style:inset;`** have triggered.
You can overcome this by adding `border-style:solid;`

### Example

```css
#nobordered {
  height: 38px;
}

#bordered {
  height: 38px;
  border-style: solid;/*main*/
  border-radius: 10px;/*your need*/
  border-width: thin;/*replicating*/
}
```

```html
<input id="nobordered" type="text" placeholder="without border radius">
<input id="bordered" type="text" placeholder="with border radius">
```

***Why is this better:***
This is better as you don't need to set border color,it sets its default border color